# Changes to nginx.conf not reflected

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am using nginx to mask my port of my node.js application on my Windows machine. I am doing this to call my application as https://localhost instead of https://localhost:3005. The following is my nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;
    #access_log  logs/access.log
    #error_log logs/error.log

    ssl_certificate      example-com.cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  example-com.key.pem;
    root  C:\Work\Code\OptimumTrunk;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

     proxy_pass http://localhost:3005/;           
    }
}
```

I would like to change my application's port here from 3005 to 8080. But when I change and restart the nginx server, it doesn't consider the change I did. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the configuration using `nginx -t`. Look at the error log.

Comment: So you are saying that you want `proxy_pass http://localhost:3005/;` to be `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;`?

Comment: @aquaman Yes. I was testing using a sample application which had port 3005  and now I want to do on my actual application which has port 8080

Comment: Check Richard Smith's comment and please show us the output. Upon restarting server, does it fail?

Comment: nginx: the configuration file C:\nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file C:\nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: It doesnt fail. It listens to only 3005. Has it got to do something about cache?